# Why hover() does not working on added class using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to delay the animation, for this task i'm adding `.startAnimation` class after 500 milliseconds for animation.

### HTML

```
<div class="layout">Hover It</div>
<div class="hoverDiv"></div>
```

### JS

```
setTimeout(function(){
            $(".layout").addClass('startAnimation');
        }, 500);
$('.hoverDiv').hide();
$('.startAnimation').hover(function(){
    $('.hoverDiv').show();
});
```

But problem is that `hover()` does not working with added class `.startAnimation` however its working with `.layout` class which is located on the same `div`. I checked `.startAnimation` class is adding properly after 500 milliseconds. Can any one guide me regarding this issue that i can fix it. I will appreciate.

Here is reference [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ayazshah/8nequ8sz/)

Comment: Use event delegation.

Comment: Use event delegation with `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events

Comment: Thanks for guiding me

Comment: Dynamically created elements you should to  use "on or live" method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event delegation with `mouseenter`, `mouseleave` events.

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.startAnimation', function(){
    $('.hoverDiv').toggle();
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/8nequ8sz/4/)

Comment: Hover is not an event, it is used for adding mouseenter and mouseleave handlers

Comment: @ArunPJohny I changed that.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan Thanks for sharing knowledge its working.

Answer (score 0):

Use mouseover event instead of hover. It will work.

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.startAnimation', function(){
    $('.hoverDiv').show();
});
```